# Debugging Blazor Webassembly with gRPC Server as Hosting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, grpc, http2

I have a Blazor WASM Application that shall be hosted inside the Backend that is implemented using gRPC on ASP.NET with .NET 5.0. When I try to debug the WASM application and as soon as the debugging Browser starts I get this error:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
  HTTP/2 over TLS was not negotiated on an HTTP/2-only endpoint.
```

All development certificates are installed and trusted and the websocket connection is established using `wss://` scheme. So from my point of view the TLS negotiation should succeed.

I already found out that I can workaround that to a certain point by changing the Kestrel endpoint settings to use `Http1AndHttp2` the problem then becomes that the gRPC connection from the frontend to the backend fails because of the downgrade to Http/1.

So my question is: Is there any option to debug Blazot WASM when using an Http/2 server on the hosting site?
If this is not possible: Can I determine somehow that the gRPC endpoints get delivered using HTTP/2 and the debugging endpoints via HTTP/1.1?

Comment: There was an issue opened on GitHub regarding the topic: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38131

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tips for checking TLS negotiation limitation on Http/2:

1. TLS version 1.2 or later
2. Renegotiation disabled
3. Compression disabled
4. Minimum ephemeral key exchange sizes:

   - Elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman (ECDHE) [RFC4492]: 224 bits minimum
   - Finite field Diffie-Hellman (DHE) [TLS12]: 2048 bits minimum
5. Cipher suite not prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is quitq simple: I used the wrong package. When using Blazor with gRPC the Grpc.Client.Net.Web package must be used (as stated in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/browser?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-grpc-web-with-the-net-grpc-client).

Then you do not have to use HTTP/2 and everything works like a charm.